# useEffect() not receiving prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm semi-new to React and learning.

I implemented a useEffect() hook as follows:

```
import { fetchDetails } from "../../ApiServices/Details";

export interface RemoveModalProps {
    id: number;
    isVisible: boolean;
    onHide: () => void;
    handleRemove: (resp: JsonResponseModel<ApiResponse>) => void;
}

const RemoveModal= ({ id, isVisible, onHide, handleRemove }: RemoveModalProps) => {
const [details, setDetails] = React.useState<DetailsModel>();

React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(id);
    async function getDetails() {
        var details= await fetchDetails(id);
        console.log(details.Data);
        setDetails(details.Data);
    }
    getDetails();
}, []);
```

However, for reasons I'm not quite able to understand, the console.log(id) is returning null. However, I have the following function just below the useEffect()

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const isValid = formRef.current.checkValidity();
    setValidated(true);
    if (isValid) {
        console.log(id);
        setSaving(true);
        const resp = await removeDetails(id);
    }
};
```

and THIS console.log(id) is logging the correct id, so obviously the id is being properly passed as a prop. What am I doing wrong with my useEffect hook that it's not able to use the prop?

Comment: what is the link between useeffect and handle submit here?

Comment: Please how to you pass props to RemoveModal?

Comment: Clearly it seems that `id` is initially null when `RemoveModal` component mounts, and *at some later time* it is updated by the time the `handleSubmit` callback is called. I guess the answer you seek lies within the parent component rendering `RemoveModal` and what it does to update the `id` prop.

Answer (score 2):

`useEffect` accepts array of dependencies as second parameter. changes in values for dependencies will trigger function in side useeffect again and again.

In your case you need `id` as dependant value in `useEffect`. So

useEffect needs to look like this

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(id);
    async function getDetails() {
        var details= await fetchDetails(id);
        console.log(details.Data);
        setDetails(details.Data);
    }
    getDetails();
}, [id]);
```

You may need to handle null/undefined value in `id`. I suggest you to do something like this.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!id) {
      return 
    }
    ... rest of hook
}, [id]);
```

I suggest you to use eslint to warn about useEffect missing dependencies.

References :

[useEffect documenation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)